# Pokemon Go unable to login with Gmail

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-go

I already played many hours of Pokemon Go, but since yesterday I am unable to login with my Gmail account. After I sign up I see this screen:

[image: Pokemon Go Loading Screen]

This screen wont change, not even after a of couple hours. I reinstalled the game twice and restart my phone but this did not fix the problem.

I am not in a country where it's released. I downloaded my game from apkmirror for Android. I tried making a Trainer Club account and switching back to Gmail, but this this does not solve the problem. The trainer account works but my Gmail account still crashes at the screen with the loading Pokeball

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you in a country where it's released ?

Comment: No I am not in a country where it's released. I downloaded my game from apkmirror for android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend had this problem too. Other accounts worked on the device and his account worked on other devices. But his own account on his own device resulted in the white loading screen. He has taken the following steps to fix it (Android specific).

- Go to Settings
- Accounts
- Google
- Sign-in & security
- Device access & notifications
- Under 'Recently used devices' click 'Review devices' and remove the device on which you can't log in.

If you open Pokemon GO again, it will ask for permission to use your google account and it should work again.

Comment: Thanks Leon!!! Het werkte, ik kan weer verder met mijn reis om de beste pokemon meester ooit te worden

Answer (score 4):

It can be one of two things:

- **You are using a "bootleg" version of the game.**

You are not using the official version of the game (you claimed to have downloaded the game from *apkmirror* for android). So there's going to be faults with the download. It's going to be worse because the developers still have a lot to fix in the game, like bugs and other mishaps.

- **Your connection just sucks.**

This has happened to me as well. Whenever I wasn't in an area with WiFi or good connection, it would log me off of my account when I entered the application. Then it would proceed to show the screen (the image you have provided) for a long time, and then give me the lame excuse of *"Our servers are experiencing issues!*

I hope this clarifies things and helps.